# Joomla: Using jQuery to load a php function

Tags: jquery, joomla, module

First off, i'm not very familiar with jQuery.

I'm building a domain check module for my Joomla website.
The basic php module works perfectly, but after submitting the form (with the domainname) the page reloads to show the result.

Because the module has to check many whois servers, it takes some time. I decided to look into jQuery for loading the results, so i can show a pretty loader and the user knows the website is checking.

My jQuery:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#domaincheckbutton').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  
    jQuery('#domainsearch').hide();
    jQuery('#preloader').show();
    jQuery.get("/modules/mod_s5_domain_check/domaincheck.php",
    {
            domainname: jQuery('#domainname').val()
    },
    function(data, textStatus)
    {
            jQuery('#domainresult').html(data);
            jQuery('#preloader').hide();
            jQuery('#resultcontainer').show();
            jQuery('#domainsearch').show();
    }).fail(function () {
         alert('There was an error collecting domain data, please report this to an administrator.');
    });
  });
});
```

The above jQuery works as expected, showing a loader and getting the result from the domaincheck.php file.. 
The problem is that the module params aren't loaded in this domaincheck.php. I think this is because the php file isn't inside the module scope anymore.

I tried adding the following to the domaincheck.php:

```
// Get Joomla! framework
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( '_VALID_MOS', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$session =& JFactory::getSession();

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_s5_domain_check');
$moduleParams = new JRegistry();
$moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
```

But this doens't work, i tried to echo some params, but they are all empty.
Besides that it's starting to look messy.. :(

I would love a solution where i can use a php function inside a 'mymodule/helper.php' file.
But how do I do this together with jQuery?
I know php (server side) is run before jQuery (client side), so a simply answer to the title of this question is No..
But i have to wait for the user to enter the desired domainname, so i know what to check.

How do I use jQuery to wait for the php function to do its domainchecking and then show the result?

Many thanks for any thoughts on this!

Regards,
Bjorn

Comment: Off topic: Instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`, do the shorthand `jQuery(function($) {`, passing `$` as an arg, and use the alias `$` inside it instead of `jQuery`. Saves quite a few chars.

Comment: Did you try using `.done()` on your `.get()`?

Comment: That will be empty of-course, because the module file you loaded is not actually assigned to any page so module parameters are not set yet. you just loaded the file and joomla framework.
Your problem can be solved but I need detail that what you want to achieve so i can help you to achieve it with an alternet way.
Are you using this file ?
https://github.com/psi-4ward/domaincheck/blob/master/languages/en/domaincheck.php

Comment: @isherwood: Yep, you're wright about the $ alias. I also noticed that, planning to do some code cleanup when it's working.

Comment: @SalilMomin: Not sure what you mean with the first sentence. Inside module php files i use $buttontext = $params->get( 'buttontext', '' ); to get the params. With the 'external' php file i use $buttontext = $moduleParams->get( 'buttontext', '' );. Notice $moduleParams instead off $params.. I try to get these params after the require framework and Jmodulehelper block. This solution is explained in many howto's to load module params in external php files. But isn't working for me. Like i mentioned, i rather dont use the external file with seperate framework loading. Thanks for the psi-4ward link